# How to use live() in ajax success callback

Tags: callback, jquery

I'm working on a wordpress site which display articles using AJAX. I added some jquery code in the success callback. One of my needs is to display an image on mouse over. All my code works except the mouse over effect.

So this is my ajax function :

```
function loadArticle(pageNumber, loop, term){    
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_var.url,
        type:'POST',
        data: someData, 
        success: function(html){
            // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
            $("#content").append(html);    

            // Zoom box
            $('img.static').hide();
            $(".ad-preview").live({
                mouseover: function() {
                    $(this).find('img.static').stop().fadeIn();
                },
                mouseout: function() {
                    $(this).find('img.static').stop().fadeOut();
                }
            });

            //  Other stuff...
        });

        return false;
    }

});
```

and the HTML :

```
<div class="ad-preview">
    <a target="_blank" href="">
        <img src="img/zoom.png" /></a>            
    </a>
</div>
```

What is the good way to implement this effect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.live is an active listener replaced by [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You would place this outside the ajax call, at the base level in js - so in other words, not inside a document.ready call or inside other functions. It will work on dom elements loaded in via ajax.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I have another question, it's about code optimisation. I have a lot of code in the success callback. I use jquery-ui slider on a specific element, I have a voting process (using AJAX too) which is executed after submitting a form etc...

Should I create another js file and put within all the code interacting with the HTML elements concerned loaded via AJAX (and not inside a document.ready call) ?

Comment: It depends on the size of your site. There's no real reason to optimize down to that level unless you're running a massive site. But some 20k users a day would not really benefit from moving a few lines of js into another file, loaded only on request. It also depends on just how much your site relies on ajax. In the end you may be making more work than needed to save a few k. I would say the only normal optimization a smaller site would need is to just minify between revisions.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you should probably be using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) rather than `live`.  Second, delegated handlers don't have to be applied in the callback.  Because they are delegated to a higher level element that remains on the page you can apply them on page load.

```
    $("body").on('mouseover', '.ad-preview', function() {
            $(this).find('img.static').stop().fadeIn();
    })
    .on('mouseout', '.ad-preview', function() {
            $(this).find('img.static').stop().fadeOut();
    });
```